# Parse XML using Python and xml.etree

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file and I'd like to read some data out of it using Python's `xml.etree`.

Let's say that the XML file is like this :

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>
         <d>This is the text I want to retrieve</d>
      </c>
   </b>
</a>
```

What I did was something like this :

```
document = ElementTree.parse('file.xml')
dToFind = document.find('d')
print(dToFind.text)
```

But it gave me the following error :

```
    print(dToFind.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XPATH` for more sophesticated parsing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) combined with `find` for finding the node recursively

In this case:

```
dToFind = document.find('.//d')
```

The documentation points to more structured parsing using `xpath` - would encourage you to look into that.

DEMO

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> content = """<a>
...    <b>
...       <c>
...          <d>This is the text I want to retrieve</d>
...       </c>
...    </b>
... </a>
... """
>>> 
>>> xx = ET.fromstring(file) #you would be doing .parse()
>>> xx.find('d') #Returns None, as it finds only first level children
>>> xx.find('.//d')
<Element 'd' at 0xf1b550>
>>> d = xx.find('.//d')
>>> d.text
'This is the text I want to retrieve'
```